# How to add files in docker container and make them accessible from other containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Short version:

I want to add files in a docker container in docker-compose or Dockerfile and I want to make it accessible from other containers that I made in docker-compose file. How can I do that?

Long version:

I have a Python app in a container that uses a `.csv` file to generate a POJO machine learning model.

I also have a Java app in a container that uses the POJO machine learning model and appends the `.csv` file. The java app has a `fileWatcher()` method implemented.

The containers are made from the docker-compose file that calls Dockerfiles for each one of them. So I want to add them this way and not with `CMD` docker commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the same named volume to different containers:

```
docker volume create --name volume_data
docker run -t -i -v volume_data:/public debian:jessie /bin/bash
docker run -t -i -v volume_data:/public2 debian:jessie /bin/bash
```

or as docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  assets:
     image: any_asset_image
     volumes:
        - assets:"/public/assets"

  proxy:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
       - assets
  volumes:
      - assets
```

Comment: I don't understand, Why nginx? and my docker-compose.yml file looks like this:
version: "3"

services:

   h2o-start:
    image: milanpanic2/h2o-start
    build: 
      context: ./h2o-start
    ports: 
      - "54321:54321"
      - "54322:54322"

   model-generator:
    image: milanpanic2/model-generator
    build:
      context: ./model-generator
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - "h2o-start"

Comment: can you explain your docker-compose.yml version a little more ?

Comment: First service is container containing images - second one is a nginx using the volumes from the first service.